# How to change the email that the contact form goes to manually in the php

Tags: php, wordpress, email, wordpress-theming

I'm using a Wordpress Theme and the option to change the email setup form is not working. So by default the emails in the contact form get sent to the admin email.

I want to change where the contact form goes to (ie: the person in charge of contact form) . So instead of trying to fix the theme problem. I'd rather just manually enter the email EXAMPLE@MAIL.COM so that it works.

Here is the code for the contact template

```
  <?php
/*
Template Name: Contact
*/
?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
          if(trim($_POST['contactName']) === '') {
               $nameError = 'Please enter your name.';
               $hasError = true;
          } else {
               $name = trim($_POST['contactName']);
          }

          if(trim($_POST['email']) === '')  {
               $emailError = 'Please enter your email address.';
               $hasError = true;
          } else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['email']))) {
               $emailError = 'You entered an invalid email address.';
               $hasError = true;
          } else {
               $email = trim($_POST['email']);
          }

          if(trim($_POST['comments']) === '') {
               $commentError = 'Please enter a message.';
               $hasError = true;
          } else {
               if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
                    $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['comments']));
               } else {
                    $comments = trim($_POST['comments']);
               }
          }

          if(!isset($hasError)) {
               $emailTo = get_option('workspace_email');
               if (!isset($emailTo) || ($emailTo == '') ){
               $emailTo = get_option('admin_email');
               }
               $subject = '[Contact Form] From '.$name;
               $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments: $comments";
               $headers = 'From: '.$name.' <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

               mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
               $emailSent = true;
          }

} ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

        <div id="content">
               <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>       
              <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                   <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <div class="entry-content">
                         <?php the_content(); ?>
                         <?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) { ?>

                          <div class="thanks">
                              <p><?php _e('Thanks, your email was sent successfully. ', 'themejunkie') ?></p>
                          </div><!-- .thanks -->

                      <?php } else { ?>

                          <?php if(isset($hasError) || isset($captchaError)) { ?>
                              <p class="error"><?php _e('Sorry, an error occurred.', 'themejunkie') ?><p>
                          <?php } ?>

                          <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="contact-form" method="post" class="clear">
                              <ul class="contact-form">
                                  <li><label for="contactName"><?php _e('Name:', 'themejunkie') ?></label>
                                      <input class="txt" type="text" name="contactName" id="contactName" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['contactName'])) echo $_POST['contactName'];?>" class="required requiredField" />
                                      <?php if($nameError != '') { ?>
                                          <span class="error"><?php echo $nameError; ?></span>
                                      <?php } ?>
                                  </li>

                                  <li><label for="email"><?php _e('Email:', 'themejunkie') ?></label>
                                      <input class="txt" type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email']))  echo $_POST['email'];?>" class="required requiredField email" />
                                      <?php if($emailError != '') { ?>
                                          <span class="error"><?php echo $emailError; ?></span>
                                      <?php } ?>
                                  </li>

                                  <li class="textarea"><label for="commentsText"><?php _e('Message:', 'themejunkie') ?></label>
                                      <textarea name="comments" id="commentsText" rows="20" cols="30" class="required requiredField"><?php if(isset($_POST['comments'])) { if(function_exists('stripslashes')) { echo stripslashes($_POST['comments']); } else { echo $_POST['comments']; } } ?></textarea>
                                      <?php if($commentError != '') { ?>
                                          <p><span class="error"><?php echo $commentError; ?></span></p>
                                      <?php } ?>
                                  </li>

                                  <li>
                                      <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
                                      <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit-button" value="<?php _e('Send Email', 'themejunkie') ?>" />
                                  </li>
                              </ul>
                          </form>
                      <?php } ?>
                    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
               </div><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
               <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
          </div><!-- #content -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>            
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Uh, why was this upvoted?? -- Look for the [`mail()`](http://php.net/mail) function in that code, change the first parameter to a fixed value then.

Answer (score 1):

The email address you send to is the first parameter of the [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function:

```
mail('EXAMPLE@MAIL.COM', $subject, $body, $headers);
```

This is not the nice way, but a quick fix. Be sure not to change or remove the original line, but only comment it out and leave a useful comment about what you have done and why:

```
//mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
//Novice change: manually entered an email address, not knowing the correct way.
mail('EXAMPLE@MAIL.COM', $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Don't take it personally, but maybe you should ask/hire someone to do this who actually knows Wordpress and PHP.

Comment: thanks. why do you say that? is stackoverflow only really for coders and not novices?

Comment: @user1784275 I guess that WP site is on the Internet, and maybe you did it for a client. Making modifications in something that you don't understand at all is dangerous. Don't take it personally, if you don't wish to. With some effort in learning PHP, you could've solved this, that's why I said what I said. Also, if SO was not for novices as well, you would not have been given an answer ;).

Comment: Ah ok. That didn't work unfortunately. any other suggestions? Thanks for your advice. I just need to get this sorted. it's actually for a friends website. I don't take it personally.

Comment: @user1784275 Could you elaborate on "didn't work"? If it was able to send an email to the admin's email address before and you specified a correct email address it must be sent.

Comment: hmm well for some reason its not working at all now. Even when I reset everything back to how it was. so no emails are going through at all now. so i'm going to try contact form 7

Comment: Thanks heaps for you help anyhow. I think it could have been the email i was using as when i changed it to another email, it worked fine. this was in contact form 7. (the original email didn't work either)

Comment: @user1784275 If you are satisfied with my answer, you can click the tick on the left of my answer to accept it.

Comment: @bažmegakapa - you can also set a value for the `workspace_email` option value, it only uses the admin email when it is not set, which would not require a code change.